# How to reuse existing task in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have question how to reuse existing task in Gradle and what is recommended way?
I would like to change some properties of reused task.

I've found that it is possible to do in dependsOn or call execute, but is it recommended way? I've read that execute is not recommended. It looks like dependsOn is better way.

Example:

```
task task1() {
    description = "task1"
    doLast {
        println description
    }
}

task callModifiedTask1ByDependsOn() {
    dependsOn {
        task1 {
            description = "modified task 1 by dependsOn"
        }
    }
}

task callModifiedTask1ByExecute() << {
    project.task1 {
        description = "modified task 1 by execute"
    }.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Calling `execute()` explicitly seems not a good idea. Mind the fact that `execute()` method is part of *internal* API of Gradle so it can potentially change.

According to reusable task You can do it exactly the same as it's done in Gradle: e.g. `copy` task. Just implement the task and configure the part that is changed for execution (e.g. `from`). Your example with `dependsOn` follows this scenario more or less.

Answer (score 1):

A task cannot be "reused", and cannot be called from another task (only depended upon). Instead, declare multiple tasks.

Comment: Peter, is it possible to declare task based on another one? It will be problem to declare another task if it is implemented in some plugin.

Comment: There is no such feature. If you can't change the plugin, you'll have to configure the task manually.